# How to find top N records from 'group by' method where N records can contain multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I was practicing with [W3 School SQL Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/). From `Customers` table I can select Number of Customers Per country by following SQL

```
select country, count(*) as NumOfCustomer 
from Customers 
group by country
order by NumOfCustomer Desc;
```

This gives me a result like this:

[image]

If I want to select top 5 countries with most customers I can not use `Limit 5` because `Germany and France` have second most highest customers and `Mexico and Spain` have fifth most highest customers.Using Limit 5 won't include `Mexico and Spain`

How can I get a result containing all `N` number of highest values where highest values can be repeated for a `N`th Number like before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank):

> Returns the rank of the current row within its partition, without gaps. **Peers are considered ties and receive the same rank.** This function assigns consecutive ranks to peer groups; the result is that groups of size greater than one do not produce noncontiguous rank numbers

```
WITH cte AS (
  select country, count(*) as NumOfCustomer 
  from Customers 
  group by country
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NumOfCustomer DESC) AS rnk
  FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk <= 5
ORDER BY NumOfCustomer DESC
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is MySQL 8.0+ only.. Otherwise you need to simulate [this](https://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-dense-rank-function-mysql-sql-query.html) with user variables or with a co-related subquery which counts which is not adviced to use.